# how can I get a value, not key from dropDownList Yii2

Tags: yii2

`yii\widgets\ActiveField\dropDownList()` in Yii2 normally returns the key in pare ['key' => 'value'] from selection. How can I get the value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the same value for key and value

in this sample country have code and name and the mao give you key value

```
  $listData=ArrayHelper::map($countries,'code','name');
```

in this sample

```
 $listData=ArrayHelper::map($countries,'name','name');
```

give you value, value

```
echo $form->field($model, 'name')->dropDownList($listData, ['prompt'=>'Choose...']);
```

Comment: thank you - it was about country selection ))